# How the Current Timeline Indicator from Schedule View works on Google Calendar Mobile app

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace, android-calendar, current-time

Would like to know the logics of Current Timeline indicator in Schedule view , especially with too many events happening at current time with different start times & End times and with many upcoming events stacked on each other in schedule view . Will be helpful to learn the logic  being used and how it works,  may be  little bit explanation  or sharing any doc which is already available.